# Sequelize - Delete association records from parent instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to find a way to remove rows from the DB through the parent model (menu) that has many children (foods). I only want to delete certain rows though, not all.

Menu.js

```
...
Menu.hasMany(models.Food, {
 as: 'foods',
 foreignKey: 'menuId',
 sourceKey: 'id'
});
...
```

In my controller I have the following to try and delete certain foods off the menu.

```
...
const result = await menu.destroyFoods({
  where: {
    name: ['Pasta', 'Pizza']
  }
});
...
```

I have also tried singular `destroyFood` as well. For both I am getting `destoryFood/destoryFoods is not a function`. Is there any easy way to do this from the instance of `menu`? New to sequelize, would love some help. Thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `menu.removeFoods()` and `menu.removeFood()` - see [Special methods/mixins added to instances: Foo.hasMany(Bar)](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#-code-foo-hasmany-bar---code-) for more information.

You will also need to use the [`Op.in` query operator](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators) to specify multiple values for `Food.name`.

```js
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

const result = await menu.removeFoods({
  where: {
    name: {
      [Op.in]: ['Pasta', 'Pizza'],
    }
  }
});
```

This is the equivalent of calling `Food.destroy()` where the `menuId` is equal to the `menu.id` from the earlier result.

```js
const results = await Food.destroy({
  where: {
    menuId: menu.id,
    name: {
      [Op.in]: ['Pasta', 'Pizza'],
    },
  },
});
```